# preg_match expression for phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, phone-number

I want to display an error message if the number doesn't match any number with hyphen, plus sign, space or brackets. No numbers either.

For example:

```
(012) 123 4567
(012)-123-4567
012-345-6789
123 123 1234
+12 23 213 3456
```

The above examples all work with this expression:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\-]|[\+0-9]|[0-9\s]|[0-9()]*$/", $_POST['tel'])) {
    $telErr = "Invalid contact number";
}
```

But it allows letters, which I do not want.

Example:

```
+00000000a
```

The above example is accepted by the expression I have.

Please can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This expression'll accept +5number, 5number

```
"'^(([\+]([\d]{2,}))([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,})|([0-9\.\-\/\s]{5,}))*$'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I first cleanup the string a bit (that avoids useless matches):

```
$input = preg_replace('/[^0-9+\(\)-]/', '', $_POST['tel']);
```

I than match an american number +1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx;

```
if(preg_match('/^(\+1|001)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})([ .-]?)([0-9]{4})/',$input))
        $result = "match: USA";

else    $result = "no match";
```

this allows for quite some input configurations - only your last number would not match (if I'd not do the cleanup first, not because of the international code which is matched, but because of the split in the area-code) all the others go also without cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Better regular expression is:

```
"/^[\+0-9\-\(\)\s]*$/"
```

Comment: This will also match ++++++++234+--

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you want to express is in the ballpark of:

```
\+{0,1}\({0,1}[0-9]{0,3}\){0,1}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{0,4}
```

that can be reduced to:

```
(\+?\(?[0-9]{2,3}\)?)([ -]?[0-9]{2,4}){3}
```

This can be read this way:

```
\+?                  //matches existence of +
\(?                  //matches existence of (
[0-9]{2,3}           //matches 2 to 3 numbers
\)?                  //matches existence of )
([ -]?[0-9]{2,4}){3} //matches a space or a dash with 2 to 4 numbers, 3 times.
```

This will give you a maximum of 3 + 4 * 3 = 15 numbers without spaces for the phone variable.

But the best way in my opinion is to trim the input and then count it's length.

In RegEx there's always a perfect matching answer, but it doesn't always means it's a good idea to use it. It can be too complicated to maintain or too hard to understand.

Answer (score -1):

SPAIN - ES

```
preg_match("/^(\+34|0034|34)?[6|7|9][0-9]{8}$/", $phone);
```

PORTUGAL - PT

```
preg_match("/^(\+351|00351|351)?[2|9][0-9]{8}$/", $phone);
```

ANDORRA - AD

```
preg_match("/^(\+376|00376|376)?[0-9]{6}$/", $phone);
```

GIBRALTAR - GI

```
preg_match("/^(\+350|00350|350)?[0-9]{8}$/", $phone);
```

--
**It will be wonderfull have all the country list**